# How to get the maximum of the sum of the sales in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple assignment but I am stuck, I have a table and need to print out the ID with the maximum total of sales. I have managed to print a sorted list of the IDs based on the sum of each one's sales:

```
SELECT "COMPANY"."ID", SUM("COMPANY"."PRICE") As PriceSum
FROM "COMPANY"
WHERE "COMPANY"."DATEOFSALE" >= DATE '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY "COMPANY"."ID"
ORDER BY PriceSum DESC;
```

I just want to show the ID and the total sales of the top selling company.
TIA

This is in Oracle, so I can't be cheap and use LIMIT 1.

Comment: you can use rownum then

Comment: But what if two or more are tied for first place? That's why I said it would be a cheap solution, heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery instead:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT "COMPANY"."ID", SUM("COMPANY"."PRICE") As PriceSum
      FROM "COMPANY"
      WHERE "COMPANY"."DATEOFSALE" >= DATE '2016-01-01'
      GROUP BY "COMPANY"."ID"
      ORDER BY PriceSum DESC
     ) c
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

In Oracle 12c+, you can use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` without the subquery.  This is the ANSI standard equivalent of `LIMIT`.

EDIT:

If you want *all* companies with the maximum, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT "COMPANY"."ID", SUM("COMPANY"."PRICE") As PriceSum,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM("COMPANY"."PRICE") DESC) as seqnum
      FROM "COMPANY"
      WHERE "COMPANY"."DATEOFSALE" >= DATE '2016-01-01'
      GROUP BY "COMPANY"."ID"
      ORDER BY PriceSum DESC
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You can replace `RANK()` with `ROW_NUMBER()` and get the previous result as well.

Comment: That's better than what I had, thanks. The only problem is when two or more companies have the same sales, which is also the maximum.

In that case it won't return all of them but just one, semi-radnomly :D